# Dependency issue when linking app to Firebase Crashlytics - maven/android/flutter

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter, crashlytics, codemagic

I am trying to set up Firebase crashlytics to my flutter app. I have followed the steps from https://blog.codemagic.io/practical-guide-flutter-firebase-codemagic/ and works fine when I run in local. However, I see a failure using the CI/CD tool - Codemagic.

== Initializing Gradle project /Users/builder/clone/android/app/build.gradle ==
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx3g

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/builder/clone/android/build.gradle' line: 7
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_8np9gq8hl982yq6pq0eovgcan$_run_closure1$_closure3@6b63e6ad] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Not sure of any solution. Reached out to codemagic support on slack!

This is now my app/android/build.gradle file looked like:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }

   maven {
       url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }

}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
   project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
   project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Expected result: The build should happen fine on codemagic

Answer (score 4):

With support from Mikhail at code magic, below is the solution:

`maven` should be inside repositories
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring_custom_repository

Like below:

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
```